# Unity 2017.3.0f3 Inconsistent emission on static objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

I'm having an issue with realtime emission on static objects. The emission itself works, but the result are inconsistent (there are dark spots alongside the lit object - please see the picture). There is a long plane with emissive material alongside the aircraft wall, which is supposed to lit the wall in it's entire length.

[Inconsistent emission on the wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43YJh.png)

The problem does not seem to be with lightmap UV-s, because directional light bakes onto the wall perfectly. I've tried to play around with light parameter settings (precomp. GI - resolution, cluster resolution etc - please see attached pic), lightmap resolution, lightmap size, but nothing seems to fix the issue. Do any of you know, what setting affects the area, that can be lit using emission - seems like something to do with too low resolution? Lighting settings - Realtime GI enabled, indirect resolution 2, lightmap resolution 80, padding 2, size 1024.

 .

[Lighting settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXrFS.png)

[Lightmap parameter settings on the wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO1R3.png)

In a simple sample scene with less complex geometry, everything works fine. I just have to get it to work with this specific geometry.

Unity version: 2017.3.0f3.

Thank you!

[Baked lightmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5VCZ.png)
[Baked lightmap closeup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah1ZF.png)
.
[UV charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9et2.png)
[lightmap UV from maya](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wDKM.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to position emissive geometric lights above the windows in the aircraft, in a narrow nook?

If so, you shouldn't use emissive lights for lights that aren't visible in reflections. Use a small area light.

You can try turning on Final Gather.

Without seeing the UV maps of the interior of the airplane hull, it's hard to tell if the artifacts are due to (1) poor positioning of the light, (2) not enough area in the UV for the shadow map, (3) bad Enlighten settings, (4) bad geometry (e.g., it has a transparent polygon that's blocking the light).

Comment: Thank you for your response!  

Yes, exactly. 

Thanks for the idea to use area lights in that location. However, I forgot to mention the reason why I went for emissive in the first place - similar lights will have to go to the ceiling and they must be editable at runtime (color and emission strenght). There the issue still persist.

I have added images of lightmap UV and baked lightmap to original post (down below). Could a too small padding in the lightmap UV cause this issue?

Comment: You should set up area lights to simulate the soft emission for the real time changes. If it looks good, it is good. The lack of control you're having right now is only going to get worse once you start playing with realtime mixed GI.